# Two questions about Riemanns Error Term R(x)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, boundary-value-problem

***Question 1*** Assume $$R(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}),$$ where  $\mu$ is the Möbius-Function and $\operatorname{li}$ is the logarithmic integral. I want to proof that $R(x)$ is asymptotic aquivalent to the prime counting function. Its pretty easy if you use the fact that $\pi(x)\sim\operatorname{li}(x)$. But if you assume that you can interchange the limit as $x$ goes to infinity with the infinite sum.  But how can you verify doing this? I would use Tannery‘s theorem, but I don't know how I can possibly find the best $M_k$ or verify that the infinite sum of $M_k$ converges. Please give me a hint. (You cant just use the fact that $\lvert \mu(n) \rvert \leq 1$ because the sum of $M_k$ would diverge.

I tried so many ways. Either it’s pretty easy and I just overlooked it or it’s harder than I thought, wich can’t be because I know it can be very rough for such a small step.

***Question 2*** This question might even be harder than the last one: Is it possible to find a good boundary for the $x$-prime number with $R(x)$?